# azure - userinfo - alias fields or get extra - Graph 1.0

Tags: azure, oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is there any option to get own fields (change fileds name, add alias or sth)? In `https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo` there were some fields like `sub`, `amr`, `aio` returned in JSON. Fields are needed by third party extension in XWIKI (not easy to fix it) :/ Fields not appear in `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`
I need to get all of them in JSON. I there any option to change returned filed name to own? Or maybe return missing fields as new fields? Values of those fields can be static, provided in URL link.... Fields just need to appear and it doens't matter what values will appear there.

Or maybe is there any option to get more fields using:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo`
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}}/openid/userinfo`

like:
`mailNickname`
`onPremisesSamAccountName`
?

So there will bo no need to use Graoh v1.0 :)

Comment: Hi, do you have a chance to look into my answer? Anything else is unclear?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it's not supported to extend fields with `https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo` endpoint currently.

If possible you could get the additional fields through `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` and handle `sub` information from `https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo` with them together in your own code.

Similar posts for your reference:

[Azure AD: OpenId Connect v2 - UserInfo not returning username, etc.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eb448c25-4630-4e2e-9d0b-7db8b7ab2e72/azure-ad-openid-connect-v2-userinfo-not-returning-username-etc?forum=WindowsAzureAD)

[azure AD, How to add user claims for OIDC /userinfo request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58762889/azure-ad-how-to-add-user-claims-for-oidc-userinfo-request)